# How to use transactions in SQLite?

Tags: database, sqlite, transactions

When i execute following SQL against an SQLite database:

```
BEGIN;
CREATE TABLE [Profile] (
[Id] INTEGER  PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
[ProfileExperimentId] INTEGER  NOT NULL,
[Name] NVARCHAR(50)  NOT NULL
)
COMMIT;
```

I get the following error:

```
27-03-2014 14:19:33: SQL Error: SQL logic error or missing database
```

I execute the SQL through an SQLite administrator tool.

If i execute the above sql without transactions the table is created.

Am i missing something? Thx in advance

Answer (score 4):

You need a semicolon `;` to terminate the `CREATE TABLE` before `COMMIT`.

Comment: I tried: BEGIN;
CREATE TABLE [Profile] (
[Id] INTEGER  PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
[ProfileExperimentId] INTEGER  NOT NULL,
[Name] NVARCHAR(50)  NOT NULL
);
COMMIT; - But but it did not work, same error message

Comment: Works for me, using the `sqlite3` tool. Possibly your tool doesn't support something you're trying to use. Also it's not displaying the actual error message, it's just translating an error code to a generic message.

Comment: Thx for the help. Okay, i have tried to use an sqlite plugin for firefox too, giving me another error message: SQLiteManager: BEGIN; [ cannot start a transaction within a transaction ]
Exception Name: NS_ERROR_FAILURE. But i can try the sqlite3 tool. :)